# Make: if test evaluation problem in uninstall rule

Tags: bash, makefile

I was following some other SO posts how to test whether directory is empty in `bash`. I wanted to incorporate it to a simple make rule:

```
uninstall:
    rm -f ~/lib/lib.a;
    if [ -z "$(ls -A ~/lib)" ]; then \
        rm -rf ~/lib; \
    fi
```

But the problem is that even though the directory `~/lib` is not empty after removal of `lib.a` the rule still gets evaluated to (copied from bash):

```
rm -f ~/lib/lib.a;
if [ -z "" ]; then \
    rm -rf ~/lib; \
fi
```

while running `make uninstall` and therefore the whole directory gets deleted...
On the other hand, if I execute the test directly in bash I get:

```
$ echo [ -z "$(ls -A ~/lib)" ]
[ -z haha.c ]
```

Why the test in the Make rule gets evaluated differently? Is it because I am running on OSX?

Comment: See [How can I check whether a directory is empty or not? ...](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dollar signs need to be escaped to prevent make from interpreting them.

```
if [ -z "$$(ls -A ~/lib)" ]; then \
    rm -rf ~/lib; \
fi
```

A simpler way to write this is to simply call `rmdir`, which will fail if the directory isn't empty. All you need to do is suppress its exit code with `-` and error message with `2>/dev/null`.

```
-rmdir ~/lib 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Within a `make` recipe, you can also suppress the error exiting by prefixing it with a `-`. Like `-rmdir ~/lib`. I like this variant, because make explicitly calls out `Error <error code> (ignored)`. Try: `printf "all:\n\t-false\n\techo hello world" > Makefile; make`